# installed new otf font but is not listed in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts

IMPORTANT: I don't have root access to machine I'm working on. I installed otf font in my home directory using http://tacticalvim.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/installing-fonts-in-your-home-directory-on-fedora-12/ fc-list lists the font. However when I try to set this font as terminal font: Right Click -> Edit Current Profile -> Font It doesn't list the font I recently installed.

Can you guys help me with it?

[EDIT]: It turns out I had to restart terminal to have font listed.

However why does preview for font look like rectangles and letters are smashed together? -- Never mind it was probably because of mucking around too much.
Deleted ~/.fonts, recreated it, copied the font and ran fc-cache.

I now have working Inconsolata font in terminal. Thank you all :)

Comment: If it isn't listed in the terminal font list, then the font is not a monospaced font, as those are the only ones listed. Or at least doesn't say that it is one. This could be fixed with fontforge but if the font isn't actually a monospaced font, the results would not be good.

Comment: thanks, I just checked and it is mono space font. I'm trying to install and use "Inconsolata" font

Comment: Are you using Fedora?

Comment: it is a red hat 5.8 server